# iir filter saturation problems

Tags: matlab, infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters

I want to implement a IIR Band Pass Filter without using MATLAB functions.
I get the coefficients as follows ($F_s$ = 1000, Band pass: 5-15Hz):

```
 f1=5;                                                                      
 f2=15;                                                                     
 Wn=[f1 f2]*2/fs;                                                           
 N = 3;                                                                     
 [b,a] = butter(N,Wn); 
 b = flipud(b')
 a = -flipud(a')
```

$b$ coefficients:

```
1.0e-04 *

-0.2915
      0
 0.8744
      0
-0.8744
      0
 0.2915
```

$a$ coefficients:

```
    -0.8819
     5.3942
   -13.7568
    18.7244
   -14.3455
     5.8657
    -1.0000
```

And I have written the filter code as below, but the output goes to infinity.

```
for i = 7 : N
    BPF(i) =  0.0001*(-0.2915*X(i) +0.8744* X(i-2) - 0.8744* X(i-4) + 0.2915* X(i-6))...
        +(-0.8819*BPF(i-1)+5.3942*BPF(i-2)-13.7568* BPF(i-3)+18.7244*BPF(i-4)-14.3455*BPF(i-5)+5.8657*BPF(i-6));
    
end
```

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to DSP.SE. I would not recommend to use the coefficients in the way you are doing it, by copying it from Matlab output. Depending on the format of the output you see only a truncated version of it. So first of all I would recommend you to use the variables `a_coff` and `b_coof` directly from the output of `butter`. For being able to replicate your results, I also recommend you to include the information regarding the input signal `x`.

Comment: hi , thanks . its just for example.

Comment: Why `flipud()`?

Comment: There's probably a $\pi$ missing in your Wn parameters too..

Answer (score 2):

This is a filter with poles very close to the unit circle so you are running into numerical problems.

Don't truncate your coefficients. You need ALL relevant digits. For example

```
   a =
      -0.881893130592485
       5.394164347627238
     -13.756839955023610
      18.724419940350913
     -14.345510766861747
       5.865659540117195
      -1.000000000000000
```

1. Use at least 32 bit floating point. 64-bit would be better
2. Implement this as cascaded second order sections
3. Don't design in transfer function form in the first place. Do it as poles, zeros and gain and convert to second order sections from there.
4. Each section should be implemented as either Direct Form I or Transposed Form II

Here is a code snippet that gets a better definition of the filter

```
%% bandpass filter design
fs = 1000;
f1=5;
f2=15;
Wn=[f1 f2]*2/fs;
N = 3;
[z,p,k] = butter(N,Wn);
sos = zp2sos(z,p,k);
format long
sos
```